# how to Fix undefined variable?

Tags: php, variables

I keep getting this Notice: Undefined variable: previouspage in /var/www/html/ies.aacrao.org/apply/copies.php on line 7 on this line of code:

```
if ($previouspage == "copies.php") {
    // _s2 variables are the shipping address for the included copy
    $first_s2 = $_SESSION['first_s2'] =  $_POST['first_s2'];
    $last_s2 = $_SESSION['last_s2'] =  $_POST['last_s2'];
    $email_s2 = $_SESSION['email_s2'] =  $_POST['email_s2'];
    $phone_s2 = $_SESSION['phone_s2'] =  $_POST['phone_s2'];
    $title_s2 = $_SESSION['title_s2'] =  $_POST['title_s2'];
    $office_s2 = $_SESSION['office_s2'] =  $_POST['office_s2']; 
    $institution_s2 = $_SESSION['institution_s2'] =  $_POST['institution_s2'];      
    }
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to fix this issue. All of these variables are supposed to be inserted into a database table and at the moment they are not getting inserted.

Comment: Well, the error message says it all. The variable `$previouspage` isn't defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: "how to Fix undefined variable?" -- Have you tried defining it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(!empty($previouspage) && $previouspage == "copies.php")
```

or

```
if(isset($previouspage) && $previouspage == "copies.php")
```

I would go with `!empty()`.

By the way, look at these functions.

Empty: https://www.php.net/empty

Isset: https://www.php.net/isset

Quick explanation:

empty checks for if the variable is defined and has a value,
isset just checks if the variable is defined.

Comment: I'd go with `isset` myself, because you immediately check if it equals a given value.

Comment: Yes you are right. :) Usually i choose empty why i go with it :)

Comment: I have the same issue in this line of code as well.  
`if (($previouspage == "copies.php") and ($xtraaddr == 0)) {
 // set session variable to trigger database work on secondary.php
 $_SESSION['redirectpage'] = "copies.php";
 // redirect to secondary.php
 header('Location: secondary.php');
 }`

Comment: Add isset or empty to that line too. Please check my answer again for the explanation.

Comment: Checking for empty will still give you the warning if your variable is not defined.

Comment: No it won't. 'Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.'